# How to use HTML markup in metadata based navigation menus

Tags: html, managed-navigation

I would like to add some custom HTML markup to my terms in my metadata based navigation menus.

So instead of

```
"Item"
```

I would like

```
"<strong>Item</strong>"
```

(or some other HTML, for example to use font-awesome icons)

When I just "customize" the link text, however, it doesn't render the HTML markup, but rather "escapes" it and displays it as code.

How to prevent this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is not possible out of the box, so you have to make your own navigation or inject javascript to change encode the existing navigation.

This is just a jquery example and has no direct link to your navigation:

```
$(".navigation").each(function() { $(this).html($(this).text()) }
```

Something like that.